# Loading native library in Quarkus application

Tags: java-native-interface, quarkus

I need to load a native library (.so file) and its java wrapper jar in a quarkus web application.
If I use System.loadLibrary call as a static initializer in my Resource, I get" Native Library /usr/local/lib/heavy_calc.so already loaded in another classloader" when the first GET request is hit.

I am running the application in IntelliJ using

./mvnw compile quarkus:dev

What is the best way to handle loading native libraries? Below is the snippet of code loading the library:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {
static {
    //export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
    System.loadLibrary("HeavyCalcJNI");
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello() {
    Calc calc = new Calc();//class from jni wrapper jar
    return calc.compute();
}
```

}

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the application? There are, I believe, still some outstanding bugs related to using JNI when a Quarkus app is run from Maven. However, they don't seem to produce the same effects that you describe.

Comment: Currently, running the application in IntelliJ using

./mvnw compile quarkus:dev

Comment: Does it work any better if you do `./mvnw package` and then run the resulting wrapper jar using `java -jar target/...` ?

Comment: It works when I do :

Comment: It works with "java -jar target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar". Although I could continue working this way, I would be curious to know if there is a better way to load native libraries than using static initializers, maybe a separate Bean with @Startup annotation might help? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure there are other things that could be tried, but I don't have any insight into what might work. I do know that there are open bugs in this area, so I presume that the maintainers are aware of the problems.